# Calc (add, sub, result)

Tags: javascript, class

I need your help, my friends.

There is a task:

Implement Calc class with ***sub*** / ***add*** / ***result*** methods.

In the constructor, we can pass the initial immutable value (by default 0), then add and subtract from it using the add and sub methods.
The add / sub call can be chained (fluent interface), the methods return a new class object.
By calling `result ()`, we get the result of the calculations.

For example:

```
const calc = new Calc();
calc.result(); // 0
calc.add(5).result(); // 0 + 5 = 5
calc.add(3).sub(10).result(); // 0 + 3 - 10 = -7

const ten = calc.add(10);
ten.sub(5).result(); // 10 - 5 = 5
ten.result(); // 10
```

This is a class

```
class Calc {
   
}
```

My try:

```
class Calc {
    constructor (num = 0) {
        this.num = num;
    }

    add (a) {
        this.num += a
        return this
    }

    sub (a) {
        this.num -= a
        return this
    }

    result () {
        return this.num
    }
}
```

The test shows it:

```
FAIL test.js
  calc
    ✓ must return an instance of the Calc class in sub methods (5ms)
    ✓ must implement fluent interface (1ms)
    ✓ must correctly implement mathematical operations (5ms)
    ✕ must ensure the immutability of class instances (2ms)
    ✕ must ensure the immutability of class 2 instances (2ms)
```

Help me to complete the task correctly, please

Comment: How can the `calc.result(10); // 0` and `ten.result(); // 10` possible?

Comment: The last `ten.result();` should output `0`

Comment: @decpk because before that there is a line `const ten = calc.add (10);`

Comment: After that line there is also a statement `ten.sub(5).result(); // 10 - 5 = 5`

Comment: `calc.result(); // 0` - you have not even managed that part so far, this returns `undefined` right now with your implementation and the initialization with `const calc = new Calc();`

Comment: `calc.add(3).sub(10).result(); // 0 + 3 - 10 = -7` - that is also not the _correct_ result - not if you manipulate the `num` value of your single Calc instance with other operations _before_ this line already. You called `calc.add(5)` before, so the `num` property now contains `5`. And `5 + 3 - 10` is `-2`, not `-7`.

Comment: @CBroe yes exactly, thanks,
i fixed and updated the post but now 2 more errors remain: 
✕ must ensure the immutability of class instances (2ms)
✕ must ensure the immutability of class 2 instances (2ms)

Comment: @CBroe apparently the one who did the task miscalculated, I agree, but this is not the problem now, I don’t know how to fix those 2 errors that remained in the test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you need to return a new Calculator instance every time you do an operation:

```
class Calc {
  constructor(num = 0) {
      this.num = num;
  }

  add(a) {
      return new Calc(this.num+a);
  }

  sub(a) {
      return new Calc(this.num-a);
  }

  result() {
      return this.num;
  }
}
```

Comment: no it didn't work

Comment: I misstyped, 'num' to 'number'. Now its correct. Could you ty again?

Comment: `✕ must ensure the immutability of class instances (6ms)

✕ must ensure the immutability of class 2 instances (2ms)`

Comment: the same mistakes remained

Comment: Final edit, i think it should now work. Could you try it please?

Comment: great my friend!
 yes it works